# Selecting class name of a span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span like this

```
    <span class='class_name'> blah blah </span>
```

I want to select the class name of this span. for that iam using this.className
its working fine in firefox. but for explorer its not...

How can i fix that??

Comment: do you want to select the element with the class name or get the class name of the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be working in Explorer too. You could try, though:

```
$(this).attr('class');
```

Comment: why almost every JS-related question assume jQuery is included? :-/

Comment: Because he put a tag of "jquery"?

Answer (score 3):

Is the variable `this` pointing to the same node in IE and Firefox? You could verify that by putting an `alert(this.tagName)` or `alert(this.id)`.